# XML entities not defined and CDATA

Tags: xml, parsing

my XML is showing me an error about not defined entities because my data show special chars like & eacute; and similars... How can I fix it?

```
<track href="file.mp3" title="<?php echo $title;?> <?php echo $artist;?>" target="http://www.site.com" rel="hdefault.jpg">
  <meta>
    <![CDATA[ <a href="http://www.site.com/search" target="_blank">More info</a> ]]>
  </meta>
</track>
```

I know that I have to use CDATA but if I try:

```
title="<![CDATA[ <?php echo $title;?> ]]>"
```

it shows me:

error on line 7 at column 19: Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values

Answer (score 3):

`&eacute;` has no meaning in XML unless there is a DTD which describes what character "eacute" is *and* the XML parser is a DTD parsing one (which is a big if).

If you want to reliably represent an é in an XML document then you need to either:

- Use a literal é
- Use a *numeric* character reference

If you want to embed HTML in an XML document, then you either have to use:

- CDATA markers around the content of an element (**not** an attribute). (As you are doing for the value of the meta element)
- character references for the special characters in the HTML. `&` is represented by `&amp;` so if you want to represent the HTML `&eacute;` in an XML document then you would need `&amp;eacute;`.

The title attribute is probably intended to be "the title" and not "the HTML representation of the title" so using a literal é is probably your best bet here.

Unfortunately, you appear to have HTML in your raw data instead of text so you might have to clean up the incoming data before you can use it.

Comment: @MikelGarcesEtxebarria — Yes there is. Very first bullet point sums it up in 4 words (although there is a proviso in the last paragraph). It can't be fixed with CDATA.

Comment: I want to show as in the register is, é or & eacute; but I don't want to crash the file, and now the files is crashing... and not only with eacute, with all &...

Comment: You said that in the question. The answer remains the same. (Although you would obviously substitute a literal *whatever* for the literal é).